# Пунктуация при присоединительном члене — дополнении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, дополнение

*В-третих, они сами бы охотно помогали тебе расти **— своей поддержкой, ресурсами, —** поскольку им хочется видеть тебя наравне с собой, при условии, конечно, что это хорошие друзья.*

Можно ли так расставить знаки препинания при присоединении дополнений? Запятые бы  недостаточно сильно выделили присоединённые члены, а скобки бы слишком ослабили связь с предложением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*В-третьих, они сами бы охотно помогали тебе расти — своей поддержкой, ресурсами, поскольку им хочется видеть тебя наравне с собой, при условии, конечно, что это хорошие друзья.*

Тире ставят **перед** присоединительной конструкцией, а с двух сторон выделяется вставная конструкция. Поскольку у вас именно присоединение дополнения,а не попутное замечание, то второе тире не нужно. К тому же дальше следует придаточное предложение в позиции **после** главного, запятая здесь на месте, а тире только отдалит его от главного, ослабит причинно-следственные связи.

Comment: Правда, у Розенталя присоединительные конструкции с тире все стоят в конце преложения.

Comment: "Присоединительные члены предложения, не имеющие специальных вводящих слов и выступающие в качестве разъясняющих добавочных сообщений, отделяются знаком тире. Они стоят в конце предложения..." (http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123)

Comment: Так ведь и здесь в конце простого предложения, дальше-то идёт придаточное

Answer (score 3):

В-третьих, они сами бы охотно помогали тебе расти — **своей поддержкой, ресурсами,** — поскольку им хочется видеть тебя наравне с собой (при условии, конечно, что это хорошие друзья).

Я  оставила бы такое оформление, то есть **вставку с двумя тире**, так как вставные конструкции имеют разнообразную тематику, иногда достаточно близкую к тексту предложения, например:
*Нас хорошо кормили, но воды — **не питьевой, а для умывания** — было мало* (Кав.).
[**Знаки препинания при вставках**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128)

Здесь важно учитывать **интонацию**: два тире соответствуют двум паузам (вставочная интонация),  а одно тире — это встроенная конструкция, не выделяется паузами.

Можно последнюю фразу заключить в скобки.

Comment: Но ведь здесь не внутри предложения, а на стыке двух предложений, так что скорее присоединение, нежели вставная конструкция.

Comment: Вставные конструкции на стыке часто встречаются.

Comment: Поддерживаю. А последнюу часть можно дать с разной степенью "нажима" : (1) после запятой; (2) в скобках;  (3) как отдельное предложение.

Comment: По-моему, для вставок как раз характерно, что они значительно выпадают синтаксически из основного предложения. Там обычно вносятся замечания добавочного характера. У нас же информация имеет пояснительный характер.